# Find maximal $R$ for which polynomial $f(z)=az^2+bz+c$ is one to one for $|z|<R$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find maximal $R$ for which polynomial $f(z)=az^2+bz+c$ is one to one for  $|z|<R$. I have arrived at an expression and need help with final assumptions or formal ones.

If $a=0$, then $R=\infty$. If $b=0$, then $R=0$. Otherwise, let $z\ne w$ with $f(z)=f(w)$, then $a(z^2-w^2)+b(z-w)=0\Rightarrow (z-w)(a(z+w)+b=0)\Rightarrow z+w=-{b\over a}$, that is $z=-(w+{a\over b})$. I am really confused when it comes to translating it into a radius. Some calculations show that $|z|=|w|$ which really makes no sense (I suppose). I could use help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** By completing the square, we can write the quadratic in the form as $$f(z) = a(z - h)^2 + k.$$ In particular, $f$ is symmetric under reflection $\phi_h$ through the point $h$; by the F.T.A., for all $w \in \Bbb C$ the only values of $z$ such that $f(z) = f(w)$ are $z$ and $\phi_h(z)$.

Comment: Would that mean $R=|h|$ then? Just to make sure I got it.

Comment: Yes, that's the right conclusion, though one should say a little more than the content of the hint to justify that claim, I think.